# Magento Docker container stops at "Running Magento install script"

Tags: magento2.3, docker, magento-install, magento-setup

I am new to Magento and Im trying to setup a Magento developer environment on Windows 10 machine with Docker. I'm using Bitnami Magento images and I managed to start up MariaDB and Elasticsearch docker containers as mentioned in the [Bitnami Magento](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-magento) documentation. Once I started Magento container it stops from below log line (docker logs magento)

[image: docker logs magento]

[image: docker ps]

The magento container is not up as well. I tried several things to find out why this happens but I couldn't find out why. Any idea on this would be really helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best option is to [raise an issue](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-magento#issues) to the Bitnami team and ask for help there.

> If you encountered a problem running this container, you can file an
> issue. For us to provide better support, be sure to include the
> following information in your issue:
>
> Host OS and version Docker version (docker version) Output of docker
> info Version of this container The command you used to run the
> container, and any relevant output you saw (masking any sensitive
> information)

Comment: Thanks Diana, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

Add the environment variable BITNAMI_DEBUG = "true"

in my case I was using MariaDB 10.9 but this image fails in this case with a max db version of 10.6

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else has this question:

This seems to be normal the first time you fire up the Magento container.  If you look at the Magento logs, it keeps going:

docker logs magento_magento_1

Keep running this command every so often, until you see:

/opt/bitnami/apache/bin/httpd -f /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/httpd.conf -D FOREGROUND'

At this point, you can open your browser to http://localhost and you'll see the default Magento storefront.

Open your browser to http://localhost/admin, and you can start configuring your store.  Login with user / bitnami1

It will take a few minutes, but eventually you'll see the Dashboard.  If not, look at the logs again.